# CGImageMaskCreate specify color for mask image

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, cgimage

How can specify mask image color for extracting a part of image?

I have found this code:

```
- (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```

As Apple doc says:

> The image to apply the mask parameter to. This image
>   must not be an image mask and may not have an image mask or masking
>   color associated with it. mask     A mask. If the mask is an image, it
>   must be in the DeviceGray color space, must not have an alpha
>   component, and may not itself be masked by an image mask or a masking
>   color. If the mask is not the same size as the image specified by the
>   image parameter, then Quartz scales the mask to fit the image.

I have blue source image:

[image: source image]

and I have image with specified colors:

[image]

So based on these colors I want to extract a part of image from the source image and it also will be great if I can detect center coordinates of extracted images in the source image. Right not problem is that using DeviceGray colors I need to have one source image and five mask images, but instead of it I want to specify color which I want to extract and have only 2 images - source and "mask" image.